# Replacing multiple bar (special char) with tab using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a string like this

```
BRADI5G20430|BRADI5G20430.1||1
```

How can I replace the bar (single and multiple) with tab ("\t")?
I tried this but dont' work

```
sed 's/\|+/\t/g'
```

I also want to include this line in bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to escape the `+`

```
$ sed 's/|\+/\t/g' file
BRADI5G20430    BRADI5G20430.1  1
```

or you can use `-r` option of sed, but this time, the `+` will be "one or more" and you need to escape the "|" since in regex, it means alternation.

```
$ sed -r 's/\|+/\t/g' file
BRADI5G20430    BRADI5G20430.1  1
```

or use awk, set field separator to "|" and then set output field separator `OFS` to tab `\t`

eg

```
$ awk -F"|" '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" file
BRADI5G20430    BRADI5G20430.1          1
```

this replaces each tab with "|". If you want to replace all "|" with one tab

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\|+/,"\t")}1' file
BRADI5G20430    BRADI5G20430.1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the command you are looking for is actually

```
sed -e 's/[|]\{1,\}/\t/g'
```

Sed does not use the `+` syntax for one-or-more, but allows you to specify an open ended number of repititions.  See [here](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/sed.html) for more information.

Comment: sed does use `+`, you just need to escape it if not use `-r`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure off the top of my head why `+` doesn't work, but this will:

```
$ echo  "BRADI5G20430|BRADI5G20430.1||1" | sed -e 's/\|\{1,\}/\t/g'
BRADI5G20430\tBRADI5G20430.1\t1
```

Answer (score 1):

How didn't it work?

Hint: if you see how it didn't work, you should be able to see what you need to do to make it work -- try removing parts and see how the behaviour changes.

Hint #2: it's the `+` part that sed doesn't recognize.

`sed 's/\|\|*/\t/g'`